# Why might res.clearCookie() instantly delete the cookie in the browser even without maxAge: 0 or expires?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

**Environment:** express: 4.17.1, express-session: 1.17.2

**Background:**  I'm experimenting with cookies.  When my logout endpoint is hit with a `fetch` request I use the following code to terminate the session.

```
req.session.destroy();
```

It works as expected.  The session is destroyed, the user is logged out and the cookie in the browser remains.  When the cookie was created `maxAge` was set to 2 hours so the fact it isn't deleted makes sense.

However, when I add this second line not only is the session destroyed but the cookie in Chrome is deleted instantly.

```
req.session.destroy();
res.clearCookie(process.env.SESSION_NAME);
```

In `res.clearCookie` I'm not adding `maxAge: 0`, `expires` or any other attributes to the cookie.  I only reference the name of the session.

**Question:** Why does the second line cause the cookie to delete?  Although I'm glad I figured out how to delete the cookie I'm not sure why this is happening.  I was under the impression that I couldn't delete a cookie from the server directly.  To remove a cookie we had to expire them.

Comment: `Why might res.clearCookie() instantly delete the cookie in the browser` Thats what its designed to do.  `In res.clearCookie I'm not adding maxAge: 0, expires or any other attributes to the cookie. I only reference the name of the session.` The function sets the `expires` time for you, since thats its purpose.